# php - 2 identical string showing different lengths

Tags: php, string, strcmp, bin2hex

I am having a problem comparing 2 identical strings. The first string is retrieved from a database and the other hard coded.

The string is `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }`.

I've first run this code and the database string has a length of 79 character and the hard coded string has a length of 39 characters.

```
echo '<pre>';var_dump($json_data);echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';var_dump('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }');echo '</pre>';
```

After some searching it was suggested to use `bin2hex()` and using that i've narrowed it down to the `"` character.

Replacing the database value with a `"` and running the following code outputs

`2671756f743b` for the database value and `22` for the hard coded value.

```
echo bin2hex($json_data)."<br>";
echo bin2hex('"')."<br>";
```

What is the correct way to get both values to compare using `strcmp()` as based on the comparison i will be doing other code.

Comment: What is var `$json_data`? Is there string, or JSON object?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do with bin2hex function. Also you don't show the code which does the query and how data is stored.

Comment: `2671756f743b` is `&quot;`, the html entity for a quote character; [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) will convert it to an actual quote character

Comment: @Warrior, the `bin2hex()` function was just trying to find out what was different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark Baker, I had to `html_entity_decode()` the database value and now both values match.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where 2 strings appeared to be the same, managed to figure out an issue on one of the strings the following way.

- `json_encode()` the string, this would result in a **null**
- run `json_last_error_msg()` to get any encoding errors. Got *Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded*
- run `utf8_encode()` on the string did the trick to fix encoding errors.